# How to add start menu shortcut with install4j silent installer

Tags: install4j, silent-installer, startmenu

How can i add start menu shortcut with the install4j silent installer. Though i am able to add desktop shortcut with the help of one variable present in the response file. But for the start menu i  did not find any variable or any switch. So please let me know if there is any variable or switch available to do this or is there any way to achieve this using **sys.startMenuDir** variable.

Thanks,
Dams

Comment: All actions work equally for the GUI and the unattended installer, so you don't have to do anything special.

Comment: Thanks Ingo. -VcreateDesktopLinkAction$Boolean=true is working for both desktop and start menu and as you said observed same behavior for GUI as well.